# How to create a Generic Dependency Injection Container creator using SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, simple-injector

I have a method inside a library like below which is based on SimpleInjector 3.3.0:

```
    public static Container GenerateContainer(ScopedLifestyle lifestyle, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = lifestyle;

        container.RegisterSingleton(container);
        container.RegisterSingleton<IIocContainer>(new IocContainer(container));
        container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var mapService = new Func<Type, bool>(serviceType =>
            {
                var serviceRegistration = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == serviceType);
                if (serviceRegistration != null)
                {
                    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                    switch (serviceRegistration.Lifetime)
                    {
                        case ServiceLifetime.Transient:
                            e.Register(Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(e.UnregisteredServiceType, () => serviceProvider.GetService(e.UnregisteredServiceType), container));
                            break;
                        case ServiceLifetime.Scoped:
                            e.Register(Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(e.UnregisteredServiceType, () => serviceProvider.GetService(e.UnregisteredServiceType), container));
                            break;
                        case ServiceLifetime.Singleton:
                            e.Register(Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(e.UnregisteredServiceType, () => serviceProvider.GetService(e.UnregisteredServiceType), container));
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });

            if (!mapService(e.UnregisteredServiceType) && e.UnregisteredServiceType.IsGenericType)
                mapService(e.UnregisteredServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        };

        return container;
    }
```

I could easily access in one of my .net core projects like below using SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore 3.3.0:

```
Container container = GenerateContainer(new AspNetRequestLifestyle(), services);
```

but I recently upgraded SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore to 4.0.10 and where `AspNetRequestLifestyle()` is deprecated. But if I try to use the suggested one:

```
Container container = GenerateContainer(new AsyncScopedLifestyle(), services);
```

I get the following runtime exception:

> An error occurred while starting the application. You are trying to register Container as a service type, but registering this type is not allowed to be registered because the type is ambiguous. The registration of such a type almost always indicates a flaw in the design of the application and is therefore not allowed. Please change any component that depends on a dependency of this type. Ensure that the container does not have to inject any dependencies of this type by injecting a different type. Parameter name: TService

```
SimpleInjector.Requires.IsNotAnAmbiguousType(Type type, string paramName)
SimpleInjector.Container.RegisterSingleton<TService>(TService instance)
Web.AspNetCore.Services.SimpleInjectorHelper.GenerateContainer(ScopedLifestyle lifestyle, IServiceCollection services)
AspNetCore.Areas.Config.Ioc.Configure(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration) in Ioc.cs
+
Container = SimpleInjectorHelper.GenerateContainer(new SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.AsyncScopedLifestyle(), services);
AspNetCore.Areas.CloudStorageArea.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in PluginArea.cs
+
Ioc.Configure(services, Configuration);
Web.AspNetCore.AreaRegister.ConfigureAreasServices(IServiceCollection services)
AspNetCore.TestHost.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Startup.cs
+
AreaRegister.ConfigureAreasServices(services);
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Can you lost the full stacktrace?

Comment: Updated the stacktrace!

Comment: The stacktrace implies that you are calling `RegisterSingleton(container)` inside the `GenerateContainer` method. Please show more details of this method (or simply remove this call).

Comment: I tried removing the call but was getting "The Identity is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope". Anyways, Updated the GenerateContainer() method, thanks!

Comment: The message is a bit misleading, but the container instance is automatically resolved. You don't need to register it.

Comment: btw, your current method of trying to map from Simple Injector to the built-in container is littered with flaws. I would urge you to stop persuing this path. Note that libraries should not use a container at all, only the startup path should have a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This prevents you from having to use an abstraction over your DI container.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: But if you really need to keep the built-in container around and want to automatically cross-wire stuff, you can take a look at this extensions: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/442#issuecomment-317423080